# Javascript: Two output when not using var keyword

Tags: javascript

Google Chrome and Firebug give me two different outputs with this example.

if b gets global, then first should give me undefined and second one 14. right? but in firebug, it gives two 14s and Chrome gives reference error.

```
function a() {
      b = 14;
}
console.log(b);
a();
console.log(b);
```

Comment: `b` isn't global in your code.

Comment: @MelanciaUK: It is in loose mode. In strict mode, it's a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: Just ran this in Firebug and gave me a Reference Error. I managed to get an undefined and 14 after adding `var b;` at the start.

Comment: Don't trust firebug on this, as it can execute asynchronously. The correct result is reference error. `window.b` would give `undefined`.

Comment: @R.Schifini firebug gave me this at first, but after hitting run button several times, it gave me two 14s.

Comment: @Meysam: That just means that `a` had been run, and created the `b` global, so subsequent runs of the code had a global to output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the browser console for scope experiments. Different browser consoles run your code in different ways.

If you run that code exactly as quoted in a normal environment, the correct thing is that you'll get a `ReferenceError` from the first `console.log(b)` line:

```
function a() {
      b = 14;
}
console.log(b); // ReferenceError
a();
console.log(b);
```

Even in loose mode, trying to read the value of an undeclared identifier is a `ReferenceError`.

If we remove that initial `console.log`, we'd be in an area that varies depending on loose vs. strict mode:

```
// In loose mode
function a() {
      b = 14;
}
a();
console.log(b); // 14
```

That's *The Horror of Implicit Globals*;<sup>1</sup> in loose mode, assigning to an undeclared identifier creates a global variable.

Vs.

```
// In strict mode
"use strict";
function a() {
      b = 14;   // ReferenceError
}
a();
console.log(b);
```

...which is how it should be.

---

<sup>1</sup> *That's a post on my anemic little blog.*

Comment: Doesn't it work like this? at compile time, **var b** goes up(globalize). when it's time to run the program, b, for the first output evaluates to **undefined**, and second time 14.

Comment: @Meysam: There is no `var b` in your code, so no, that's not how that code works. **If** you had a `var b` in global scope, it would work differently, yes.

Comment: @Meysam there is no "compile time". And you don't have `var b`. And that doesn't make `b` "go up" as in globalize - the variable will be _hoisted_ but not up a scope but just to the top of the declaration.

Comment: @Meysam: Just for the avoidance of doubt: Assigning to an undeclared identifier does create a global, but that doesn't happen at parsing time (loosely, compile-time); it happens at runtime, when that line of code actually executes.

Answer (score 3):

The first `console.log()` should give ReferenceError, because the variable is not defined at that time. If it behaves differently in Firebug, then it's a bug in Firebug.